# How to set "max_allowed_packet" property from spring application.yml

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I need to change "max_allowed_packet" property for mySQL data base from SPRING property file (application.yml). I found some topics about that, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518419/changing-max-allowed-packet-property-with-hibernate-configuration).

They proposed to use mySQL command line:

```
$>mysql --max_allowed_packet={some_value}
```

But maybe someone know new solution for this task? It would be great to have this ability.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing max\_allowed\_packet property with Hibernate configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518419/changing-max-allowed-packet-property-with-hibernate-configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change `--max_allowed_packet` property from spring application.yml file, because this is a mysql server property. Therefore you should set this property when you start the mysql server.

You could add it in my.cnf, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size)